# Angular how to pass parameters into an injected service

Tags: angular

I have a data service (dataservice) that gets data based on a passed in parameter.  Dataservice is injected into a second service (resultservice) that will call methods on the data service to get data.

In my angular component I inject resultservice but I need to pass it a GroupId parameter.  What is the right way to do this?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { DataService} from './data.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ResultService {

  protected groupId;
  private results$ = new Subject<any>();
  
  constructor(
    private dataService: DataService, 
    groupId: number
  ) { 
    this.dataService.getResults(groupId) //this groupId value is what I need to pass in from my component
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.results$.next(res);
      })
  }

  getResults(): Observable<any> {
    return this.results$.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Component

```
constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, 
    private competitiondata: CompetitionDataService,
    private platform: Platform,
    private resultService: ResultService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => 
      this.groupId = params['groupId']; //how do I pass this value to the ResultService so that it can be passed to the DataService???
      this.results = this.resultService.getResults();
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the groupId as param for the getResults() function.

```
Public getResults(groupId): Observable<any> {
    
    return this.dataService.getResults(groupId)
    
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get results based on the route parameter, the right way of doing it would be using [resolve service](https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data).

Result Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ResultService {

  protected groupId;
  private results$ = new Subject<any>();
  
  constructor(
    private dataService: DataService
  ) { }

  getResults(): Observable<any> {
    return this.results$.asObservable();
  }

  initDataServiceWithNewGroupId(groupId) {
    this.groupId = groupId;
    return this.dataService.getResults(this.groupId)
      .pipe(
        tap(res => {
        this.results$.next(res);
      })
    )
  }
}
```

Resolver:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ResultService } from './result.service';


@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ResultsResolver implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(private service: ResultService) {}

  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  ): Observable<any>|Promise<any>|any {
    const groupId = route.paramMap.get('groupId');
    return this.service.initDataServiceWithNewGroupId(groupId);
  }
}
```

Component:

```
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit  {
  groupId;
  results;

  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private resultService: ResultService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // You can get results from acticated route
    this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(data => {
      this.results = data.results
    });
  }
}
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularresultservice?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts) is the live example.